# If $A$ is an $n$ $\times$ $n$ matrix, show that $A^2=0$ $\implies$ $Im(A) \subseteq Ker(A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

And prove/refute the converse.

I know that I need to show that any vector in the image (range) must also be in the kernel (nullspace) of $A$.

I don't understand. If $A^2=0,$ what are the possible values of $A$? 
Regarding the image, if I know A, I can just take linear combinations of of its columns.
Regarding the kernel, if I know these values, then I can just solve $A\vec x=\vec 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

So you can see that my main problem is finding the possible matrices $A$ which satisfy $A^2=0$.

Could anyone offer any hints?
Thanks

Comment: The point is that you don't need to *find* all the matrices such that $A^2=0$.

Comment: You just need to assume that $A$ is some matrix which you found running around in the jungle of matrices. It doesn't want to tell you its components, but it tells you only that $A^2=0$, so that's all you know and you should work with that property.

Comment: Right, so, conversely, suppose $x \in Ker(A)$. Then there exists a $y$ such that $Ay=0$. But where do I go from here?

Comment: You apply $A$ on both sides of the equation. Then you get $A(Ay)=A(0)$. Now simplify!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathrm{Im} A$. Then there exists $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ay=x$. Applying $A$ on that equation gives

$$Ax = A^2 y = 0$$

That means $x\in\mathrm{Ker} A$.

So we have shown $\mathrm{Im} A\subseteq \mathrm{Ker} A$.

*Note*:

The converse is also true:

If $\mathrm{Im} A\subseteq \mathrm{Ker} A$, let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now $Ax\in \mathrm{Im} A$, therefore also $Ax\in\mathrm{Ker} A$, i.e. $A^2 x = A(Ax)=0$.

Comment: Why is it that $A^2 \vec x=0 \implies A^2=0$ (on the last line)?

Comment: @user127192 Because $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is an *arbitrary* vector. If a matrix is $0$ on all vectors on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then it must be the zero matrix.

Answer (score 4):

Choose $x$ in $\mathrm{Im} A$. There exists $z$ such that $x=Az$. Hence $Ax=A^2z$ and $A^2z=0$ because $A^2=0$. Thus, $x$ is in $\ker A$.

Now, try your hands on the converse.

Answer (score 4):

In fact there's a more general result and it's an equivalence

$$AB=0\iff \operatorname{Im} B\subset \operatorname{Ker}A$$
since

$$A(\underbrace{B x}_{\in \operatorname{Im} B})=0\iff Bx\in \operatorname{Ker}A$$